# I can't get video selected from gallery swift

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

My code is here

```
@IBAction func openVideo(_ sender: Any) {
        //selectVideo(delegate: self, sourceType: .savedPhotosAlbum)
        let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
        mediaUI.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
        mediaUI.delegate = self
        self.present(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

At this part I select video.

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func processVideo(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]){
        
        let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! URL
        print("hey") 
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            let vcPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
            vcPlayer.player = player
            self.present(vcPlayer, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
         
        }
        
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I can't get any print in processVideo function. I get this error after selecting the video from gallery.

```
"Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by changing name of processvideo func to imagePickerController. It seems like name is very important at delegate functions. I didn't notice that.

Tip for creating this delegate function write didfinish and you will get prefer function named imagePickerController, use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set for settings like this or in plist.

```
switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
    case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
        self.setupCaptureSession()
    
    case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
            if granted {
                self.setupCaptureSession()
            }
        }
    
    case .denied: // The user has previously denied access.
        return

    case .restricted: // The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
        return
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios)

Comment: I set plist to ask allow camera and for gallery before. I'm recording a movie and saving it. But when i try to pick something from gallery, get nothing. I don't get the error message anymore don't know why.